# Is there a particular reason why package.json files need to be lower case?

Tags: node.js, package.json

I was reading on node's website that "it can only contain lowercase letters...because when a package is published on npm, it gets its own URL based on this property". But with this being said, is there a reason why a URL can't contain a capital letter? I am thinking this capital letter would still be acceptable but clearly it isn't. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Only thing I know is that URLs are case-insensitive, so capital letters do not matter at all for URLs. Filesystems on the other hand (other than Windows), are case-sensitive.
However, what exactly are you asking here? If they say that you cannot do it, then you cannot do it. Only a core developer would be able to answer that question any better than all of us probably can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr: filesystem-level case-sensitivity.

UNIX filesystems (that is, the piece of software that manages where files start and end) are **case-sensitive**.

This means a file named `foo` is different from a file named `FOO`, etc.

> NPM packages are not allowed upper case characters in their name, seemingly because unix filesystems are case-sensitive, which creates "a recipe for confusion and nonportable software".

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63419456/14133230)